# Does $\log\varLambda \leq - \log(b)$ imply $\log\varLambda \leq - \frac{\log(b)}{12}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation

Let, $\alpha_2=\frac{a+1}{a}, \alpha_1^k =(\frac{xz}{y^2})^k \leq \frac{1}{b}$, then, $$\varLambda := \log\alpha_2- k\log\alpha_1$$

In the paper [linear forms in the logarithms of real algebraic numbers close to 1](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/ConfMumbaidef.pdf), it is written on page $9$ that

> On other hand, a short calculation yields 
>      $$ \left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \left(\frac{xz}{y^2}\right)^k\right|\leq \frac{1}{b} \quad (13)$$
>   thus, we have, 
>    $$ \log\varLambda \leq - \frac{\log(b)}{12}$$

we see there is a $12$ as ***denominator!!*** , the claim is-
$$\log (\log\alpha_2- k\log\alpha_1) \leq - \frac{\log(b)}{12}$$
$$ \implies \log\varLambda \leq - \frac{\log(b)}{12}$$.
Why $-\log b$ is divided by $12$?

**So, how do we derive,** $\log\varLambda \leq - \frac{\log(b)}{12}$ 
**from** $ \left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \left(\frac{xz}{y^2}\right)^k\right|\leq \frac{1}{b}$ ?

**Image of the page :-**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
$$(a+1)(ab^2+1)\gt (ab+1)^2$$
and so
$$b(a+1)(ab^2+1)\gt b^{1/12}(ab+1)^2$$
from which
$$\alpha_1^k=\frac{(a+1)(ab^2+1)}{(ab+1)^2}\gt b^{-11/12}\tag{*1}$$
follows.

By the mean value theorem, there exists a real number $c$ such that
$$\frac{\log{\alpha_2}-\log{\alpha_1^k}}{\alpha_2-\alpha_1^k}=\frac 1c\qquad\text{and}\qquad \alpha_1^k\lt c\lt\alpha_2\tag{*2}$$
from which
$$\alpha_2-\alpha_1^k=c(\log{\alpha_2}-\log{\alpha_1^k})=c\varLambda $$
follows.

It follows that 
$$\begin{align}\log\varLambda&=\log\left(\frac{\alpha_2-\alpha_1^k}{c}\right)
\\\\&=\log(\alpha_2-\alpha_1^k)-\log c
\\\\&\lt \log\frac 1b-\log{\alpha_1^k}\qquad\qquad (\text{from $(13)$ in the paper and $(*2)$})
\\\\&\lt -\log b-\log{b^{-11/12}}\qquad\qquad(\text{from $(*1)$})
\\\\&=-\frac{\log b}{12}\end{align}$$